# expire not clicked email containing Cloudpages link

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, landing-page, cloudpagesurl

When an e-mail containing a link to a landing page configured with CloudPage is sent to cutomer, is it possible to expire the link if the customer did not click the link within a specific time period (e.g. 48 hours)?

Comment: Sure it is. What have you tried to do, in order to implement it? We are happy to help you, but expect some research and initial work prior to asking questions on this forum.

Comment: Through my research https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_url_expiration.htm&type=5 as help doc says, we found it is not possible  within 48 hours. I am asking through here as I could not find any matching document. Can you give me detailed info about it?

Comment: You will need to build a custom solution with ampscript. Include the timestamp where the email is sent in the CloudPagesUrl function, and compare it to current system time in the cloudpage. If the difference is more than 48 hours, redirect to a fallback URL. Otherwise: show the cloudpage.

Comment: Thank you Lukas for your help!